# Vuetify, how to use v-pagination to display every next two, three sites

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vuetify.js

Im trying to find a solution to modify my pagination component. I want to display every two or every three sites using vuetify pagination component. The basic version allows to display every single page.

Template:

```
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-pagination
      v-model="page"
      :length="4"
      prev-icon="mdi-menu-left"
      next-icon="mdi-menu-right"
    ></v-pagination>
  </div>
</template>
```

script:

```
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        page: 1,
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Data table:

```
            <v-data-table dense

              v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :single-select="singleSelect"
    item-key="name"
    show-select
    class="elevation-1"
       :items-per-page="7"

  > </v-data-table>
```

Comment: what do you actually want?? What are every two/three sites??

Comment: hello @tuhin47, I use v-data-table on my website (I added code recently to my question),I want to use pagination component with my v-data table but in standard I can choose only one page range in my table using this pagination component, I want to have an option to display even (next two) or odd (next three) pages with data on my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement functions for `next` and `previous` events. Here I write a function for clicking the `next` event. This occurs two field shifts.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      page: 1,
      length: 6
    }
  },
  methods: {
    next2() {
      if (this.page + 1 <= this.length) {
        this.page = this.page + 1;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <div class="text-center">
        <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="length" prev-icon="mdi-menu-left" next-icon="mdi-menu-right" @next="next2"></v-pagination>
      </div>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. But can you give me a hint how to occurs two fileds on one click? Its still working for one:)

Comment: One Increment is the default for clicking the next button. I just increment plus one to make that 2

Comment: Ok, I have a warning: [Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "next": got undefined

Comment: Maybe its incorrect but it started working when I replaced @ next to @ input.
Now I can controle it to even or odd